# Which shell ruby uses as its subshell?

Tags: ruby

If I do

```
`echo $SHELL`
```

, I get `/bin/bash`.

But if I try to run this loop:

```
`for x in {1..20}; do echo $x; done`
```

I get `{1..20}` instead of expected 20 numbers.

Maybe ruby uses some other shell to run those commands? How can I work around this?

**EDIT:** Software versions:

```
$ irb --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: I get `"/bin/bash\n"` and `"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby uses `sh` as the subshell for backticks and #system. `$SHELL` is your default shell, `$0` should tell you your current shell. You can get your desired shell by specifically invoking it

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
$ irb --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> `echo $0 -- $SHELL`
=> "sh -- /bin/bash\n"
irb(main):002:0> `bash -c 'echo $0 -- $SHELL'`
=> "bash -- /bin/bash\n"
irb(main):003:0> ENV['SHELL']
=> "/bin/bash"
irb(main):004:0> system 'bash', '-c', 'echo $0 -- $SHELL'
bash -- /bin/bash
=> true
irb(main):005:0> system 'echo $0 -- $SHELL'
sh -- /bin/bash
=> true
```